# Why does mp4 video included in video tags not playing?

Tags: html

I included a .mp4 video file and I only get the starting image of the video, it is embedded in  tags. Why is it not playing?

```
  <video>
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
```

Comment: please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add controls in the video tag
<video controls>

Answer (score 0):

I guess this might help: [HTML5 Video](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) by HTML5Rocks.

You could also try to add controls for debugging:

```
<video controls>
```